# Media queries not taking with ionic project

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am working on a Ionic project with the api from [The Movie Database](https://www.themoviedb.org)

As you can see from the image I have a grid of poster covers. On the iPhone 5 (tweaked it with css) and iPhone 6Plus you can see that the grid is center. But on the iPhone 6 its a little off.

It tried to fix this with media queries but if I make a change then the grid changes also for the iPhone 5 & iPhone 6Plus.

My question is how to just adjusted the layout for the iPhone 6 without messing the layout for the iPhone 5 & iPhone 6Plus.

Part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="row responsive-sm responsive-md responsive-lg wrapper-grid">
    <div class="col col-33">
        <div class="">
            <a ng-repeat="trending_movie in trending_movies" href="#/app/trending/{{trending_movie.id}}">
                <img ng-if="trending_movie.poster_path" ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/{{trending_movie.poster_path}}" >
                <img ng-if="!trending_movie.poster_path" ng-src="{{default_image}}">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Part of my CSS code:

```
/* GRID PAGE */
.wrapper-grid{
  padding-left:15px;
}

/*  MEDIA QUERIES */
/*@media(max-width:750px) and (max-height:1334px){
    .wrapper-grid{
        padding-left:40px !important;
    }
  }
*/
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest using media queries with the width between iPhone 5 and iPhone 6Plus:

```
@media (max-width:413px) and (min-width:321px) {

}
```

This will change whatever your css is between this values. When the browser is between 413px and 321px wide, the within the media queries will be applied.

Comment: did you add a media query between the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6Plus? If it still does not work, would you mind creating a fiddle?

Comment: ok here is my JsFiddle, although for some reason my grid one work like in my actual app ... (http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/hb7lu/). sorry something went wrong. just give me a minute

Comment: Hey it is broken on my end. The fiddle is blocking the dummy pictures. Did you do anything on your end to make it work?

Comment: the jsfiddle works with me. try it again -> http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19732/ it should work now ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94639/discussion-between-victor-luna-and-gy22).